# Reading docusign audit logs

Tags: logging, docusignapi, audit

I would like to read docusign audit logs like who, when the document was signed? I looked at the rest api for requests log but it is returning only limited records (restapi/v2/diagnostics/request_logs). Any idea where and how'll I get the detailed audit and admin logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong endpoint, correct endpoint is

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/audit_events
```

More details for above end point are available at [ListAuditEvents](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listAuditEvents/)

Instead of always doing polling using APIs to know the envelope status or recipient status, I would recommend you to use DS Connect. DS Connect is like webhook, it will push the XML message to you for the subscribed event. This way you will always get the update from DS whenever any event is happening on the envelope.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. Is there a way to get all envelope ids for a specific timerange?

Comment: @RajatPaliwal: List of envelopeIds is is not linked to this qs, can you please accept the answer if it answer your initial qs and open a new post for your second query.

Comment: I got what exactly I was looking for. Thanks again for your help!